# OpenWeatherMap's Weather map PNG is not overlaying properly on Open Street Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openstreetmap, react-leaflet, openweathermap

devs I am trying to implement a simple weather map that shows temperature using react.

So far I have successfully created a map and have been able to overlay an image from OpenWeatherMap's Weathermap API.

[image]

now when I overlay them, there is zoom offset and location offset. I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but no use.

You can see my code here on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-borg-0vlcf1?file=/src/WeatherMap.js)

how do I solve this?

also, I'm trying to convert latitude and longitude to X and Y using the formula from
[this website](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#ECMAScript_(JavaScript/ActionScript,_etc.))